# How to run nested for loops in ParDo of Apache beam in google Dataflow and return json of dict

Tags: python-2.7, apache-beam

I run this code in my local pc it works, but when I tried to run it in google dataflow it gives me an error. I found the location of the error, which is in ParDo function. The first loop returns the value as desired however the second loop giving me an error. Can anybody suggest an alternative approach or figure out where is the issue.
The element['content'] is URL giving the location of the file with JSON data

class DimTrans(beam.DoFn):

```
def process(self, element):
    import pandas as pd
    import apache_beam as beam
    data = pd.read_json(element['content'])
    title = data[:1]
    data = data[1:]
    for idx, item in data.iterrows():
        for dim, axis in item.items():
                label = (title[dim].values[0])
                d = {'axisDim': int(dim),
                     'axisOrder': int(idx),
                     'axisValue': float(axis),
                     'axisTitle': u'{}'.format(label)}
                yield d
```

Error trace:

An exception was raised when trying to execute the workitem 533970500833477506 : Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 642, in do_work work_executor.execute() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 156, in execute op.start() File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 38, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start def start(self): File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 39, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start with self.scoped_start_state: File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 44, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start with self.spec.source.reader() as reader: File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 54, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start self.output(windowed_value) File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 175, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output cython.cast(Receiver, self.receivers[output_index]).receive(windowed_value) File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 85, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value) File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 403, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process with self.scoped_process_state: File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 404, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process self.dofn_receiver.receive(o) File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 569, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive self.process(windowed_value) File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 577, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process self._reraise_augmented(exn) File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 602, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented raise File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 575, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process self.do_fn_invoker.invoke_process(windowed_value) File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 352, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process output_processor.process_outputs( File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 673, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs self.main_receivers.receive(windowed_value) File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 85, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value) File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 403, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process with self.scoped_process_state: File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 404, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process self.dofn_receiver.receive(o) File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 569, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive self.process(windowed_value) File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 577, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process self._reraise_augmented(exn) File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 618, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented six.reraise(type(new_exn), new_exn, original_traceback) File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 575, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process self.do_fn_invoker.invoke_process(windowed_value) File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 352, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process output_processor.process_outputs( File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 651, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs for result in results: File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/GCP/test1file.py", line 56, in process File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2668, in **getattr** return object.**getattribute**(self, name) AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'items' [while running 'Print Results/ParDo(DimTrans)']

Comment: What is the error? Can you post the trace?

Comment: I have added @anton

Comment: The AttributeError looks to be telling you that `items` is not a method defined on a Pandas `Series`. Perhaps there are different pandas versions being used? I believe you'll need to use `iteritems()` on a Series rather than `items()`

Comment: Thanks, yes resolved the issue